# Firefox can not open PDF in mac os x

Tags: mac, firefox, pdf

when I click into ome link using the last Firefox (3.6.x) on Mac OS X (last snow leopard), it always asks me to save the file instead of opening it automatically. I check in applications and select "preview" for all PDF types, but it does not mind. Do you know any fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - the https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pdf-plugin-for-firefox-on-mac-/ addon