# Mac OS X can only view online PDF in Safari

Tags: macos, firefox, google-chrome, pdf, osx-mountain-lion

I use Chrome and Firefox to view PDFs online almost every single day. However, from yesterday I noticed that PDFs cannot be opened in both of them. The only browser can open a PDF document online is Safari.

This is the error that I got from Firefox when trying to open PDFs:

```
[18:56:30.824] Error: Bad end offset: 940 @ resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:126
```

I did an experiment by trying to open PDFs from "Google filetype:pdf". The result shows that the above situation happens on almost every PDF document (over 99%).

Below are my configurations:

- OS: Mac OS X Mountain Lion.
- Firefox: Firefox 25.0.1
- Chrome: Chrome 31.0.1650.63
- Installed PDF Reader/plugins: The built-in Apple Preview. **No other PDF readers or plugins.**

Does anyone encounter the same problem? Is there any solutions to address this?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/259107/firefox-can-not-open-pdf-in-mac-os-x?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I saw the above thread early before. However, it is not relevant and does not solve the problem. :-(

Comment: Has your machine always had this issue with FireFox? If not you may want to try running the Repair Disk Permissions under Disk Utility. You can also try to re-install firefox

Comment: Hi Falconspy, thank you very much for your suggestions. However, even after I repaired the disk permissions and reinstalled Firefox and Chrome, the problem is still there... :-(